# is it possible to merge cells in 'class grid' of google apps script?

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

im trying to organise elements using grids and some need more rowspan or colspan. How can I achieve that? My google app script standalone app > https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwvCnn7WfTWsU2sz-8ONeM_gLM_y5pZd31s6lb68bjyx1bETOyy/exec

the code but not yet updated to the app:
https://script.google.com/d/1H6DLb8L6Qd3g55Dzn_A7ed61QvM_OcrLINDfya1i1h7JAyV_jLH7nmcq/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered a very kludgy workaround for the lack of `colspan` in GAS...

1. create a table (`FlexTable`, `Grid`, etc.) with the columns/row you want
2. when you get to an area where you'd like to use `colspan` or `rowspan`, create a new table (with different cell widths and heights
3. keep on creating a new table every time you want to change the cell widths or heights
4. create a `VerticalPanel` and add each of the tables you created in steps 1-3 in order

You now have the *appearance* of a single table with `colspan` and `rowspan` features.

Not very elegant, but it's the only solution I've been able to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FlexTable widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_flextable) that is meant precisely for this purpose

Comment: r u kidding me? there is no such method as getFlexCellFormatter() to set colspan or rowspan in GAS? How else can i make it happen? http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/3a79y0CWl80